# How to get marker tag information on get event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-gmap3

Using the jquery `gmap3` plugin, I have this function, and basically when it runs, its supposed to loop through all the markers on the map, and alert their tag data. But this code isn't working... Does anyone know how to do this?

This alerts `undefined`. However the marker is being returned, I just don't know how to get its tag data.

Thanks.

```
function search_markers() {
    var map_id = "#my_map";
    var value = document.getElementById('tags').value;

    $(map_id).gmap3({
        get: {
            name:"marker",
            all: true,
            callback: function(objs) {
                $.each(objs, function(i, obj){
                    //obj.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png");
                    alert(obj.tag);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "document.getElementById('tags')" Are you using same id for different elements?

Comment: Theres an input field with an id called `tags`. I plan to get its value, and then only show the markers that has its tag value equal to the input field text value. I'm not using same id for different elements, I am able to get the value of the input field.

Comment: replace alert(obj.tag) by console.log(obj) or alert(JSON.stringify(obj) in order to know if it is not just the name of the property that is different from the one you expect.

Comment: If I try `console.log(obj);`, then it says `[object Object]` on the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mapaZonaPoligono').gmap3({
    get: {
        name:"marker",
        all: true,
        callback: function(objs) {
            $.each(objs, function(i, obj){
                $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
                  alert( key + ": " + value );
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)